# Calling a controller method from laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I have a method in my base controller.php that formats all my responses to how I like it like so;

```
public function sendError($error, $errorMessages = [], $code = 404)
{
    $response = [
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $error,
    ];

    if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
        $response['data'] = $errorMessages;
    }

    return response()->json($response, $code);
}
```

If I am calling it from another controller, i simply just call

```
return $this->sendError('Validation Error', $validator->errors(), 400);
```

But i am also using middleware for my JWT-Auth. Instead of re-writing the method, is there any way to call this controller method from inside middleware?

Comment: Maybe you can build the controller instance using `app(YourControllerNameHere::class)`, and call the method using `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: `return (new yourChildController)->sendError('xyz errro',[],400)`  create instance of controller

Comment: @JigneshJoisar that has worked, is there any chance your could add an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one in middleware by create of your controller

```
return (new yourChildController)->sendError('xyz errro',[],400)
```

Answer (score 3):

First get the **existing** instance:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// ...

$myController = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getController();
```

Then call as you would normally, in OP's case:

```php
return $myController->sendError('My error message.', [], 400);
```

> **Note** that above is tested with Laravel 6.x release.

Answer (score 1):

in your middleware

```
$request
        ->route()
        ->getController()
        ->myMethodOnMyController($data);
```

tested on laravel 9

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the [other recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71780399/1255289), just uses `$request->route()` instead of `Route::getCurrentRoute()` facade method.

Comment: ha-ha-ha. You missed a year. The other answer is a year old. But I upvoted it. You can upvote both or the best one. I personally don't like Facades, because it is a hidden dependency. And I tested it on on Laravel 9